# How to install ThinkingRock v2.2.1?

Tags: 11.10, installation

http://www.trgtd.com.au/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=45&Itemid=58#linux

is the link for this Java program for organising your projects/activities. Java is working on my system.
I know this as I'm able to use JDownloader successfully.

However attempts to install Thinking Rock have all failed. All the info I've found appears out of date (it is an old free version, to be fair). I did not have any luck adding either PPA source that I found to my software sources either via GUI or in the command line. No, sorry that's possibly misleading. I can add the software sources (though perhaps wrongly) but installing then gives an error after a long list of activity. (see at end)

http://ppa.launchpad.net/crazyscot/tr/ubuntu
also salutis/ubuntu
(both oneiric main)

Following instructions, thinkingrock (nor thinking nor rock) did not show up in Synaptic search. Command line methods didn't work either. To be frank I am still winging it when it comes to installing software on (L)ubuntu. Almost completely clueless!

Please help, somebody. I'm sure it's something pretty simple that I'm doing wrong!

Rob

INSTALL ERROR:
Err ...ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err ...ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err ...ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err ...ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err ...ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err ...ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err ...ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found

(... replaces http://)

Answer (score 2):

The PPA you pointed to does not have a package available for Oneiric (11.10) or later.

This explains your 404 errors.

Looking at [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com), thinkingrock has never been an official package in the repositories.  Thus you will not find it in Synaptic.

Looking on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/thinkingrock/files/ThinkingRock/TR%202.2.1/), there appears to be a rather large sources.zip available.  Thus in theory you can download, compile and install as per the [wiki instructions](http://www.trgtd.com.au/wiki/doku.php?id=dev%3ausesource).

I note there is now a company that has taken the opensource version and up'd its version to v3 and [requires a license key](http://www.trgtd.com.au/) etc.

If you like a challenge - use the wiki instructions to compile and install.  If you want an easy life ... perhaps an alternative such as [wunderlist](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/how-to-install-wunderlist-in-ubuntu.html) might be easier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the heads up about wunderlist. It looks something I could use. Just spent the past hour or more finding out about a whole load of stuff I wasn't aware of like Titanium. So if a PPA isn't available for a later version of Ubuntu, can you use the PPA for an earlier version? The install from source for tr looks hellish...

Comment: Possibly you could - but you could mess up your system.  I'm assuming that you are relatively new to linux.  As such, I would not recommend it until you are more confident how to diagnose & rollback something that cannot  be fixed by the usual `ppa-purge`.